# Что то вроде *.rtf (или *.md, но с картинками) - нужен редактор для такого формата

Tags: html, поиск-программ, редактор, редактор-текста

Уважаемые коллеги,

хочу спросить совета насчет программы.

В очередной раз пишу документацию. в очередной раз надо сдеать страничку, куда вставлено несколько картинок в окружении страницы - двух текста.

В очередной раз чертыхаюсь, потому что в любом вики для этого есть *редактор*, в котором есть три кнопки, которых мне хватает на все случаи моей однообразной жизни: вставить картинку, сделать выделенный текст жирным, сделать выделенный текст италиком.

Ничего больше не надо!

Wordpad решал эту задачу виртуозно, но он ушел в верхнюю тундру вместе с форматом rtf. Сейчас такое людям предлагать - как предлагать поковырять им в носу, все хотят открытых форматов - то есть HTML.

Нет ли вордпада для такого чудовищно простого HTML?

Хочется, чтобы это а) была локальная программа, а не сервис, работающий в браузере б) она была бесплатной (ну, извините, глупо *платить* за функциональность, которая на два миллиметра выше плинтуса) в) визивиг. Ну, то есть, WYSIWYG - если я выделил и нажал на кнопку "болд" - то текст у меня на экране становится болдом.

Буду благодарен за советы, а то уже кинулся сам писать, но вовремя остыл.

Comment: Файлы картинок могут лежать отдельно рядом с основным файлом или принципиально должны быть встроены внутрь файла?

Comment: Но вообще Wordpad поддерживает и docx, и odt, оба открытые — не то?

Comment: Для markdown попробуйте [typora](https://typora.io) (сейчас его похоже сделали платным, но можно поискать бесплатную бета версию)

Comment: Ну как минимум она WYSIWYG и поддерживает изменение форматирования горячими клавишами (те же стандартные Ctrl+B, Ctrl+I). Вставка картинок тоже работает, можно настроить куда будут сохраняться вставляемые изображения. Для меня самая главная фишка - умеет конвертировать скопированный с какого-нибудь сайта форматированный текст со ссылками в markdown (через нее иногда копирую текст причины  закрытия вопроса в комменты).

Comment: @insolor - спасибо, попробую еще один подход к ней сделать. Возможно, я с первого раза не разобрался, как ей пользоваться